# how to configure sharepoint site on internal network

Tags: sharepoint

I have created sharepoint application for internal use. But it is not accessed in network, but my sharepoint Central Administration site is accessed on network. Plz tell me what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many things you can do to find out how this happened.
1. Can you access the application from the server itself?
..1). If not, check the IIS and SharePoint log file to see if the site is up.
..2). If yes, check your firewall configration, may it block your app's port or block your users
2. Your site has any site head? Have you have your DNS points to it?
3. Have you put your users into the site's member group?
4. Check your SharePoint server's windows event log, is there any error message in the Application catelog?

Anyway, you must first make sure the site is up and then make sure your end users can reach it.